# How can I minimize future long-term reward in deep Q-learning?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I’m trying to implement deep Q-learning on a problem were the *rewards* the *agent* receives are errors from another model. The RL agents job is to minimize the long-term reward (error) instead of maximizing it as is typically the case in Q-learning.

So what I wonder is, how can the conventional DQN target value equation:

$$\mathrm{Target} = r + \gamma * \max(Q(s’))$$

be rewritten for RL problems were the feedback from the environment (reward) should be minimized instead of maximized?

(I realize that multiplying the error with negative 1 converts any minimization problem to a maximization task, but for sake of brevity I won’t dwell on why that’s not ideal to do in my situation).

Comment: Since multiplying by $-1$ is the easiest answer, and the only one that immediately comes to mind, I think you should indeed explain why this is not possible for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two changes you must make if you want to minimise a cost instead of maximise a reward.

1. Change the Q value TD target to

$$\mathrm{Target} = r + \gamma * \min_{a'}(Q(s’, a'))$$

NB I have added in the action to be explicit what the minimisation is over, it should be in your formula too. Also kept with the symbol $r$, although you might want to go with $c$ for cost.

2. Action selection should be based around minimum Q value. E.g. the greedy action choice in state $s$ is now $\text{argmin}_{a} Q(s,a)$

---

As commented on your question, there is not usually a good reason to do this, when you can just use negative cost as a reward. However, you may see this used in e.g. zero-sum games, alternating between min and max operations depending on the player.

Comment: That was exactly the answer I was searching for! Thank you, I will try it out!